# Get current page number when user click on a pdf page in web

Tags: java, jsp, pdfbox

In my jsp page i'm displaying pdf by using html object. Here i need to get the page number on which the user made a click.
here is my jsp code in which the pdf document is displayed.

```
<div class="showpdf" style="margin-left: 10%;">
    <object id="pdfPage"
        data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/<%=session.getAttribute("fileName")%>"
        type="application/pdf" width="191" height="207" title="">
    </object>
</div>
```

here is my servlet

```
File file = new File("D:/IIV 3 Project/Documents/Invoices/invoices/"+fileName+"");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type",    getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
         Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: What did you try yet? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jpzef I've edited the question. till now i'm able to view pdf document in jsp page. Now my next requirement is onclick to find the page number.